# redirect javascript, replace url

Tags: javascript, redirect

I try to redirect user through a new page, but

```
window.location =
```

or

```
window.location.replace()
```

or

```
window.location.href =
```

Append the new url to current url and doen't replace it

Here is my code

```
<div id="header">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function set_lang_as_en() {
        if (location.protocole) {
            window.location = location.protocole + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '?lang=en';
        } else {
            window.location.href = location.host + location.pathname + '?lang=en';
        }
    }

    function set_lang_as_fr() {
        if (location.protocole) {
            window.location = location.protocole + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '?lang=fr';
        } else {
            window.location.href = location.host + location.pathname + '?lang=fr';
        }
    }

    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="set_lang_as_en();return false;" >
        <img src="images/lang/usa.png" title="Change langage to english"></img></a>

    <a href="#" onclick="set_lang_as_fr();return false;" >
        <img src="images/lang/france.png" title="Changer la langue pour français">    </img></a>

    <span id="title">TITLE</span>
</div>

<hr />
```

for example if my url is

```
http://127.0.0.1/~user/index.php
```

and I click on the link, then my new url is like :

```
http://127.0.0.1/~user/127.0.0.1/~user/index.php?lang=en
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo at `location.protocole` - should be `location.protocol`.

```
              //here ↓
if (location.protocole) {
     window.location = location.protocole + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '?lang=en';
                             //and here ↑
```

In both of your functions.

Since we're at it, simplifying your code a bit with [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.search) and [drying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.protocol#Browser_compatibility) it up we get:

```
function set_lang(lang) {
     location.search = '?lang=' + lang;
}
```

Then you can call it with `set_lang('fr')` and `set_lang('en')`.

This will only update the query string part of the URL, keeping the same protocol, hostname and pathname.

Comment: You right, it why I needed "if", I'll accept your answer when I'll could. This kind of error that's pretty hard to debug, thanks

Comment: @Epitouille No problem, I've updated the answer with a simpler solution as well.